# How to remove spaces introduced by as.formula?

Tags: r, formula, whitespace, gsub

`as.formula()` was used in a loop as follows:

```
survFormula <- as.formula(paste0("surv",sep="~",names(sel.col.list[[i]][j])))
survFormula[[998]]
```

which introduced the space between `e - 5` as shown below:

```
surv ~ X8ALL.Cytotoxic.T.cell3.10501148854251e - 5
```

I successfully used `gsub()` to remove the space, but that changes the `class` to character. I used `as.formula()` with `gsub()` in it to change from `class: character` to `class: formula` once again:

```
as.formula(gsub(" - ", "-0", format(survFormula[[998]])))
```

But that ignores the gsub() and spaces are introduced back!

```
surv ~ X8ALL.Cytotoxic.T.cell3.10501148854251e - 5
```

The removal of spaces is crucial because the output of my formula has to match my column names. My column name is like this:

```
X8ALL.Cytotoxic.T.cell3.10501148854251e-05
```

Please help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you just make your column names syntactically valid. You can do that with `make.names`.

```
names(df) <- make.names(names(df))
```

After doing this rest of your code should work without any error.